# should I avoid using Firefox sync in Tor/Orfox?

Tags: firefox, orbot

The title kind of explains the question, but I'm not a security expert and would appreciate an expert's opinion and reasons.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Voted to close this as primarily opinion based, there are no good answers yet but they have been asked. The functionality is still in Tor Browser but in at least some circumstances it will definitely harm anonymity. There is an open ticket for reviewing this at [#10368](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/10368) and an example of it breaking anonymity at [#7188](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/7188).

Comment: Ah, excellent. Thank you for pointing me to those tickets!

Comment: It's worth noting that you can select what you want synced. Ticket #10368 only applies if you sync preferences, but you can choose to only sync bookmarks if that's what you want.